# CSS Grid auto rows height issue in Firefox ESR

Tags: css, firefox, css-grid, grid-layout

I use grid layouts to display a bunch of 16:9 aspect ratio divs with a background image. It works really well in all the modern browsers, until one client told that their company uses Firefox ESR, which seems not to have latest grid features.

I've experimented a little and looks like it can't get this dynamic elements height. If I add `height: 61px;` to the `.media-element` class, it works, but the aspect ratio can't be kept anymore. I suppose the issue is with `grid-auto-rows` property that it can't read non explicit height value, but that's only a guess.

Here is how it looks like in that browser:
[image: Image in Firefox ESR 60]

And how it should look and do in other browsers:
[image: Chrome in this case]

Have anyone encountered this issue before? What's the real problem and does it have any solutions? 
I really don't want to make rows height fixed because I need that 16:9 aspect ratio. 
Or is there maybe another way to force elements to keep their aspect ratio using only CSS without any JavaScript?

```css
.grid-content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 4px;
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: start;
    align-content: start;
    min-width: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.media-element {
    border: solid 1px #17353f;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    position: relative;
    background: #EEEEEE;
}

div.preview-img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-content">
  <div class="media-element">
    <div class="preview-img" style="background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/acLOzS1.jpg)"></div>     
  </div>
  <div class="media-element">
    <div class="preview-img" style="background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/acLOzS1.jpg)"></div>     
  </div>
  <div class="media-element">
    <div class="preview-img" style="background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/acLOzS1.jpg)"></div>     
  </div>
  <div class="media-element">
    <div class="preview-img" style="background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/acLOzS1.jpg)"></div>     
  </div>
  <div class="media-element">
    <div class="preview-img" style="background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/acLOzS1.jpg)"></div>     
  </div>
  <div class="media-element">
    <div class="preview-img" style="background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/acLOzS1.jpg)"></div>     
  </div>
  <div class="media-element">
    <div class="preview-img" style="background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/acLOzS1.jpg)"></div>     
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See the duplicate I posted. The problem has been resolved in the newest version of Firefox.

Comment: I know it's working in the newest versions of Firefox. The problem is those people aren't allowed to use it. Only Firefox ESR.

Comment: I understand. Now you know the problem.